# API call creates multiple connections to database

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I am creating a front end to show the data returned from the API, I have multiple API's. I am using jquery ajax method. The API's have text and images which are to be shown to the user. When I set view (table) for text only and call API multiple times and check the processlist of mysql I see only 1 live connection which refrshes everytime I make an API call.

But, when I set view to display text with images (images are in array), each API call creates new connection (most of the time) and this connection never dies.

How do I handle this issue?

Comment: Please add the code you have used , to your question. There could be some issue or difference in the code for both text and images. Can suggest something based on your code.

Comment: But its a lot of code, I am storing response locally in array, creating table row from array data and using for loop to create images.

Comment: Issue must be something related to your code. Check the code related to images and see if you are making an API call/DB connection for every image. Just some thought..